# Python telnet connection closes after unknown time

Tags: python, telnet

How long does a python telnetlib's telnet connection lives?

every time I am using it, it gets disconnected after a period of time. (regardless of what I am writing or reading).

When using Windows telnet connection to the same server, its not getting disconnected, or at least, keeps alive much longer then Python's.

I couldn't find anything documented about it in all the versions of Python telnetlib documents.

RFC 854 also didn't gave me the answer.

Windows XP, Python 3.3.

Thanks.

A code for example by request:

```
>>> t=telnetlib.Telnet("*.*.*.*")
>>> t.write("su".encode('ascii')+b"\n")
>>> t.read_eager()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 427, in read_eager
    self.fill_rawq()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 573, in fill_rawq
    buf = self.sock.recv(50)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Now, the thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it wont, (I am not using the same connection obviously) , sometimes I can do more writing and more reading one after eachoter and sometimes not.
The exception is also changes from time to time.

Other applications using Telnet to connect to the same server works perfectly.

Comment: Does it close when idling, or in the middle of a transmission? Do you get an error message? This is probably a glitch in your setup, not a feature of Python.

Comment: Let us see your code, please.

Comment: Your error message indicates that the computer to which you've connected (apparently named `*.*.*.*`) has closed the connection.